# Update fragment based on user inputs in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an Activity with 3 fragments attached(using viewpager) , Whenever a user in any fragment changes the date range I need to load the relevant data from the DB  and show it in the same fragment.

Could anyone guide me to a link or  suggest  an approach to this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html) it enables you to attach an observer (using [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html)), and update the view using the [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) so anytime the data is changed in the database the view is updated straight away.

In your case the user input can go straight into the query, and once the data is fetched your view will be updated automatically. I personally have a case where I have 3 fragments in a ViewPager and they display similar data, so I use one ViewModel to fetch it.
Here is a [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) that shows how to implement it. Basically you will have a combination of a ViewModel, LiveData and Room.

Comment: I did try this code and it works well but when I close the app and reopen the app I get duplicate values in the viewmodel am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @day_dreamer Do you mean they appear twice? The thing is that `ViewModel` does not persist data through the app closure. So once the app is closed completely or the associated Fragment or Activity is closed, `ViewModel` is garbage collected. Check [this](https://medium.com/google-developers/viewmodels-persistence-onsaveinstancestate-restoring-ui-state-and-loaders-fc7cc4a6c090) article, it explains the concept well. So when you reopen the app, your `ViewModel` refetches the data from the database.

Comment: Thanks and my bad I had some flaws in my insert logic which was causing the issue.

Comment: @day_dreamer no problem :)